# oninput input listener blocks Firefox whith some characters

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying this code:

```
<input type="text" oninput="javascript:alert('asd')" />
```

It works fine in Chrome and Opera as like other browsers, but when runned in Firefox the window blocks and the OK button of the alert does nothing as soon as you put a '`', '´' or '¨' character.

I'll be grateful for any insight or solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need an alert dialog in an event handler? If that is only for debugging then consider using `console.log()`.

Comment: I'm trying to validate the input as it's written. Obviously I don't call an `alert()` directly but by a function that checks every character as it's written and shows the `alert()` if it's not a correct one, telling it to the user.